# JSON-lib NoClassDefFoundError org.apache.commons.lang.exception.NestableRuntimeException

Tags: java, android, mysql, json, apache

I'm trying to retrieve some data from a MySql database on my website. Specifically, I'm making a game (using the LibGDX framework) and would like to retrieve the top 10 high scores from the database. Here is the portion of my code that processes the JSON data

```
    JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray();
    jArray.add(result);
    for (int i = 0; i < jArray.size(); i++) {
        JSONObject jsonData = (JSONObject) jArray.get(i);
        System.out.printf("Name:%s \t Score: %d \n",
                jsonData.getString("name"), jsonData.getInt("score"));
    }
```

And here is the error I get when the code runs

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/exception/NestableRuntimeException
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:120)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/exception/NestableRuntimeException
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.me.gdxshooter.HighScores.readDatabase(HighScores.java:58)
    at com.me.gdxshooter.GameInstance.update(GameInstance.java:109)
    at com.me.gdxshooter.GameScreen.render(GameScreen.java:29)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.render(Game.java:46)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:207)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:114)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.lang.exception.NestableRuntimeException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 18 more
```

Here's a screen cap of all the jars in the classpath for my project. https://i.stack.imgur.com/siriQ.jpg
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Go to Project/Properties/Java Build Path/Order and Export -- Make sure there's a check in front of Android Dependencies and the support library, if you use it.Mark all checkboxes and Click on Apply and clean the project.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I found that to get json-lib to work I needed to have references to the following in my project:

- Apache Commons BeanUtils 1.9.1
- EZMorph 1.0.6
- Apache Commons Collections 3.2.1